# Azure CRON expression for each 15 days

Tags: azure, cron, azure-function-app-proxy

I have a function app which I want to be triggered every alternate Tuesday.
Can anyone suggest the cron expression.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Azure Functions uses standard CRON syntax. So using something like [this](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html) to build them should work:

`0 0 0 15 * ? *`

(meaning: every 15th day of a month, I hope I got your request right)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I need to trigger alternate Tuesday, can u please suggest something

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "alternate Tuesday"? Did you take a look at the link? The tool there is quite detailed to build your required schedules.